# Expand element height when content is added to the next one

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, height

I'm working on a web-app where the layout is the next :

- A left-side navigation menu
- A right-side body for content

My problem is that even though both sides `height: 100%` when content is added to the right-side, the left one doesn't expand !

I illustrated my scenario with this photo to explain more what's happening.

[UPDATE]

Here is the code snippet that I'm using for building this layout.
PS : it's an Angular app so I'm using `<router-outlet>` where I display the content's components:

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="dp-flex-display dp-flex-row dp-full-width-height">
    <aside>
        <dev-portal-side-navigation></dev-portal-side-navigation>
    </aside>
    <aside class="dp-full-width">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </aside>
</div>
```

**app.component.scss**

```
.dp-flex-display {
    display: flex;
}

.dp-flex-row {
    flex-direction: row;
}

.dp-full-width-height {
    min-width: 100%!important;
    min-height: 100%!important;
}
.dp-full-width {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image: here is my layout]

Comment: Can u create a snippet

Comment: Create a snippet please if you need help. But it seems that your main wrapper have a max-height, or your element is on absolute position, or something like that.

Comment: I added code snippet